# Can you use keyframes for motion blur in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I'm working on a motion-graphic piece in AE, and am trying to figure out if there is a way to disable motion blur temporarily. For example, say I have 100 frames of an animation, but i only want motion blur to be applied to frames 15-30 and frames 60-95. Is there a way to do this, or is motion blur just a toggle on/off?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a built-in “CC force motion blur” plugin you could add to your comp as an adjustment layer. If you use that instead of the system motion blur, I think you could keyframe it on or off, or just keyframe the adjustment layer on or off. Be warned it is slower to render than blurring the usual way.

Comment: thanks! also, how much slower is to render? like an extra 15 minutes or are we talking hours here?

Answer (score 1):

You could precomp the layers and duplicate them, so that one has motion blur and one does not, and toggle the opacity of each on/off.